# js-comint mode (node) returning too many undefined responses?

Tags: major-mode, comint, javascript, js2-mode

I am using `js2-mode` and `comint-mode` to run the Node REPL in emacs.  For some reason the prompt is returning a lot of `undefined` and `...undefined` responses, which it wouldn't do normally.  for instance, this code:

```
function run () {
    console.log('hello there');
}
function next () {
    console.log('hello again');
}

run();
next();
```

Prints out the following:

```
... ... undefined                                                                       
> undefined                                                                                                                                                                ... ... undefined                                                                                                                                                         > undefined  
> hello there                                                                           
undefined                                                                               
> hello again                                                                                                                                                                undefined
```

Comment: Why not? The results make sense to me. A function declaration doesn't produce a value, and the JS way of saying that is to say that the value is undefined. Then, after you execute `run`, it still doesn't return anything, which is again, the "sort of" unit type, i.e. undefined.

Comment: It makes sense, sure. But I doubt we seeing a bunch of `undefined`s is very helpful or pretty.

Comment: Additionally, the first line, when actually returning a value has the `... ... value` which is strange.

Comment: alos @wvxvw - by that logic there should actually be another `undefined` as `next` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The ellipsis must be a residue from indentation. I can't tell for sure. I'm certain though you'll get more of these printed when you copy-and-paste a larger block of code into the REPL. And, yes, I'd imagine there to be one more undefined. I would maybe try looking into Node's implementation of REPL, perhaps there are even ways to control it...

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts to get rid of undefined... I ended up using a shell command and send all my Javascript to node and return just the result instead of a console.

If you are interested here is the code.

```
(define-key js-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c")
    #'(lambda ()  
       (interactive)
       (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "node")))
```

Comment: you put this in your `.emacs` file?

Comment: Yes you can, depending on how you organize your code.